# How to use the suspend and resume method in Vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to know about the thread method of `Vb.net`

In my program, the Thread is working when I received data at another device

And I want to pause the thread, when I click the stop button, but there  is no supported `suspend()` method and `resume()` method. How do I use it?

(I searched the information about thread pause, but everyone use a suspend method in their program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell the thread to suspend or resume. Doing this from outside the thread would break it, which is why those types of operations are not supported.

Now, how do you send a message to the thread? There are a number of ways, but perhaps the most straightforward is to use a pair of `AutoResetEvent` objects (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx). The first object is used to signal that the work thread needs to pause. The second object is used to signal that it should resume. The work thread should either wait on or periodically check the event to determine if it needs to pause. When it does pause, it then immediately starts to wait on the second event object. When the main thread has determined that it's ready to resume the work thread, it signals the second event object, which wakes up the work thread.